# Can I ask "How to Write a SEO Plan for Website / Blog?"?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Can I ask "How to Write a SEO Plan for Website / Blog?"?

I did not still ask this question because I thought it will be closed. That's why I asked it here. I know that answer for this question is little bit hard.

Just check this question: [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Above question is a really good question as a reference question.

Can us make a "How to Write a SEO Plan for Website / Blog?" also reference question like above.

Answer (score 5):

There are entire books written about how to plan SEO for a website.   I would close that question as "too broad."   A full answer to the question couldn't possibly fit in the few paragraphs for an answer on this site.

We have tons of questions about SEO.  If you ask something about SEO that isn't as broad in scope, we can certainly answer that.